# Add djangorestframework to debian control Depends

Tags: django, version-control, debian, django-rest-framework

I installed [djangorestframework](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework). But after I added to debian control file, the error is:

```
Package djangorestframework is not installed.
```

My control file:

```
Depends: python, python-setuptools, djangorestframework
```

**Anything missing?**

Comment: What control file?

Comment: @grochmal https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html

Comment: Cool, it was similar to what i was suspecting.  I'll definitely argue that, unless you're building a `.deb` package for the django-rest-framework, you should not meddle with the dependency tree of the package manager.  Every scripting language follows its own dependency management, for python it is `virtualenv` and `pip`.  Overwriting them with `apt-get` mangles the way other users of the system may (or may not) see the python dependency tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can run

```
 pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

You can open the generated file and check the djangorestframework==3.3.3 version
or edit it and then

```
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Alternatively you can install Django Rest Framework by using

```
 pip install djangorestframework==3.3.3
```

And if needed, any of the extension modules:

```
 pip install djangorestframework-bulk==0.2.1
 pip install djangorestframework-digestauth==1.1.0
 pip install djangorestframework-extensions==0.0.3
 pip install djangorestframework-filters==0.8.0
 pip install djangorestframework-jwt==1.8.0
 pip install djangorestframework-oauth==1.1.0
```

Comment: how to add it to the control file. what is the name?

Comment: You're Debian does not need Django Rest Framework, the only place where it matters is your Django project.